Disable auto-fit behavior in Chart.js
I have made a bar chart importing variables from a database. Variables can have values from 0 to 100.
I want to maintain the X-axis fixed to 100 even when all 'real' values are lower.
I inserted the min and max specifications.
options: {
        indexAxis: 'y',
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true, 
                min: 0,
                max: 100, 
            }
        }

However, the chart still auto-fits to the maximum real value.
I also tried with the 'suggestedMin' and 'suggestedMax' and, also, setting the autoFit option to false, a with no luck.
options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    autoFit: false,
    scales: {
        y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
        }
    }
}

Is there any way to override the auto-fit behavior?
Thanks for any suggestion!

The options you shared (setting min and max for the value scale) should work; however your y axis is set to be the index axis, so it appears your bar chart is horizontal. In that case you want to set max to 100 for the x axis, not for the y axis, isn't it?

Thank you so much @kikon! Indeed. I set max for the x axis and it worked fine.
